# C# Code to display row and column number on status bar of notepad

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm writing a notepad program in C# winforms and just want to know about how can row number and column number be displayed on status bar.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an extended version of `TextBox` (assuming you are using that control) that lets you get/set the caret position:

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/10/19/C--Get-current-Caret-Line-and-Column-in-a.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link it works but the problem now is that in which event Handler would i update the line and column info because cursor position changed event is not available. So is there any way other than writing our own event so that this info can be updated on cursor change.

Comment: Since the code there uses the `SelectionStart` property, maybe the `SelectionChanged` event on the `TextBox` ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectionchanged(v=vs.95).aspx ) will do what you want?